# How to make a non-recurring HTTP request to Azure Resource via Logic App?

Tags: azure, webhooks, azure-logic-apps

I have a functionality in Azure exposed via webhook. I want to be able to invoke that from Azure portal at will. I thought of designing a logic app with HTTP trigger and running the Logic app would run the functionality. However, as shown in dashed border, it is asking for a recurrence interval indicating that it will be a recurring activity. I can't set it to 0 minutes. The condition is that whosoever wants to use that functionality should be able to do it through 1 (or few) clicks on Azure portal (someone who is not technical). My questions are -

1. How to achieve this via Logic App to call the webhook at will? (Perhaps there is a different trigger I can use?)
2. Is there some other Azure Resource that can make this HTTP call?

As a last resort I could maybe make a ADF pipeline but I believe there should be simpler ways.

[image: Logic App Design]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an HTTP Trigger, which is used for polling an API for results.

Change this to use a HTTP Request Trigger instead so that it can be invoked on deman, and call the API in the next action.

Comment: This will work for my use-case as I won't be passing any body to HTTP Request Trigger. 'Running' the logic app would trigger it and I have no use for the URL of HTTP Request Trigger as of now. Thanks. That solves it!